# Get boolean value from a class to main method. JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jdialog

I've been trying for hours to get the `boolean` value from a class to my `main` method. I want the variable `GeneralFrame`.

Also is it correct to use `JDialog` to ask the user if he is new or returned and then run my `JFrame`? Here is my code:

```
package portofoliexpense;   

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

/**
 *
 * @author AlexandrosAndreadis
 */
public class PortofoliExpenseDialog extends JDialog implements ActionListener {     
    boolean GeneralFrame = false;           

    //dimiourgia minimatos
    JPanel messagePane = new JPanel();          

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); // ftiaxnw button
    JButton existinguser = new JButton("Existing User");
    JButton newuser = new JButton("New User");

    public PortofoliExpenseDialog (JFrame parent, String title) {
        super(parent, title);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //dimiourgia minimatos
        messagePane.add(new JLabel("Hello, click one of the above to continue!"));

        getContentPane().add(messagePane);// ypodoxeas gia ola ta //components           

        buttonPanel.add(existinguser);
        buttonPanel.add(newuser);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END); // border //layout sto telos tou dialog 


        newuser.addActionListener(this);
        existinguser.addActionListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false); // den allazei megethos
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == existinguser) {
           GeneralFrame = true; 

        }

        if (source == newuser){
           GeneralFrame = false;       
        }

    }        
}
```

I tried lot things. I also used `return` but couldn't get it.

Comment: Where is the code for your `main()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for this instead of a `JDialog`.

Here is an example:

```
static boolean isNewUser;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, InterruptedException {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isNewUser = isNewUser();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Is new user: " + isNewUser);
}

public static boolean isNewUser() {
    Object[] options = { "Existing User", "New User" };
    int resp = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Hello, click one of the above to continue!", "User Type", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
    return resp == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
}
```

Comment: if you could explain the code. It'll be fine!!! And thank you, it is what i wanted.

Comment: @AlexAndreadis There is not much to be explain, all you need to know is what the `showOptionDialog(...)` method does, you can find a lot of details about that in this tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html Basically, it creates a dialogue and replace the original "Yes", "No" buttons with the values in the `options` array, waits for the user to select an option and returns the selected option as a `boolean`

Comment: also as i can see `boolean isNewUser = isNewUser();` works better instead of `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean isNewUser = isNewUser();
        }
    });

}`

Comment: @AlexAndreadis That works but since this is GUI related code, it should be executed on the `EDT`, that is why I've used `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`.

Comment: hmm ok! but with `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)` i can't get the Boolean type of isNewUser. it says Cannot find symbol. i have it on main method and after that i type ` if (isNewUser == true) { //do sth }`  . But if i use  `boolean isNewUser = isNewUser();` works perfect.

Comment: @AlexAndreadis I've edited my answer, I've defined `isNewUser` as a class variable so it can be accessed outside the `invokeAndWait(new Runnable() ... )`  runnable.

Answer (score 0):

Main method only takes in a string array:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

So, the only data you **can** send to the main method is, of course, an array. But, you want to pass in a boolean.

You know how to pass a paramater, but here it only takes in a string array. Since we want to pass a boolean, lets just pass that boolean **in** the array.

After you pass the boolean into the main method through the string array, retrieve it doing the following:

```
    boolean boolean1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(ArrayWhereIPutMyBoolean(0));
```

Now, boolean1 is the boolean that you passed in from main method!

Answer (score 0):

In the main method are you calling the variable GeneralFrame as "instance name".GeneralFrame ?